# Google Script Error - Cannot find method add

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been puzzled by this error. I have not been able to figure out what I am missing. Without the calls to headPanel the UI was working but would not insert the title or text label so I added the Horizontal panel in hopes of adding the text, but alas error. Please help me with this problem and I need to know what I am messing up.

```
function doGet(e){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var headPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('headPanel');
  var header = app.setTitle('Detention Attendance');
  var label = app.createLabel("Please enter attendance for Detention by clicking the       checkbox next to the student's name if they were present. Then click Sumbit.");
  headPanel.add(header);  //* ERROR OCCURS HERE
  headPanel.add(label);
  app.add(pane);

  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var flexTable = app.createFlexTable().setStyleAttribute('border', '2px solid black')
      .setStyleAttribute('borderCollapse','collapse')
      .setBorderWidth(2); 
  //Get Data from spreadsheet
  var spreadsheetId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';//Change it to your Spreadsheet ID
  var dataArray = getData(spreadsheetId);
 //Load data into table cells
  Logger.log(dataArray);
  for (var row = 0; row<dataArray.length; row++){
  if (row > 0) {
    var ticketDate = dataArray[row] [0];
    var dateStamp = Utilities.formatDate(ticketDate, "America/Chicago", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    Logger.log("dateStamp = " +dateStamp);
    dataArray[row] [0] = dateStamp;
    var ticketDate2 = dataArray[row] [16];
    var dateStamp2 = Utilities.formatDate(ticketDate2, "America/Chicago", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    dataArray[row] [16] = dateStamp2;
    Logger.log("DateStamp = " +dateStamp2);
    }

  flexTable.setStyleAttribute("color", "purple").setText(row, 2, dataArray[row][2].toString()).setWidth('300px');
  flexTable.setText(row, 0, dataArray[row][0].toString()).setWidth('600px');
  flexTable.setText(row, 4, dataArray[row][16].toString()).setWidth('300px');    
}  

panel.add(flexTable);
app.add(panel);
return app;
}

function getData(spreadsheetId){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange();
   Logger.log(sheet);

   return sheet.getValues();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `header` var is a [UiInstance](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-instance#) - in fact it's the same instance as `app`, returned as a convenience for chaining by the call to `.setTitle()`.

The `.add()` method is looking for a Widget as a parameter, and not finding it.

You don't need to keep that `header` var - it's only causing you trouble. In fact, you could set the Title as you create the UiApp instance:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Detention Attendance');
```